# How to use `sed` to print from between one line and another line?

Tags: sed

Suppose a file with such content:

```
a
x
y
z
c
some to be omitted
a
b
c
```

I want to print all those lines which are between the "a" line and "c" line (both with and without the "c" line are ok):

```
a
x
y
z
c
a
b
c
```

I tried the sed command:

```
sed -n '/a/{:my_tag /./p; N; /c/ t end; t my_tag; :end}'
```

and it gives me the output:

```
a
a
```

Does the N in the command work for once only? I cannot see any loop work out here.
the help info of sed is a little bit confusing and it seemed like I was doing in the wrong way.

Or maybe some tools rather than sed would be more helpful and efficient to this problem and please show me how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following(if ok with `awk`).

```
awk '/^a/{flag=1} flag; /^c/{flag=""}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
a
x
y
z
c
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed -n '/^a$/,/^c$/p' file
```

or

```
sed '/^a$/,/^c$/!d' file
```

Output:

```
a
x
y
z
c
a
b
c
```