# Print all lines between two patterns (which may not be pairs) with AWK/SED/GREP

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I know there have been multiple instances of this question such as [Print all lines between two patterns, exclusive, first instance only (in sed, AWK or Perl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55220417/print-all-lines-between-two-patterns-exclusive-first-instance-only-in-sed-aw)
but my question is for if the two patterns may not be paired - for instance

given input

```
PATTERN1
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
PATTERN1
ggg
hhh
iii
PATTERN2
jjj
PATTERN2
kkk
```

I would expect the shortest range as output:

```
ggg
hhh
iii
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested based on your shown samples only in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
/PATTERN1/ && found1 && !found2{
  found1=found2=val=""
}
/PATTERN1/{
  found1=1
  next
}
/PATTERN2/{
  found2=1
  if(found1){
    print val
  }
  found1=found2=val=""
  next
}
{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
' Input_file
```

Output for given samples will be:

```
ggg
hhh
iii
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                              ##Starting awk program from here.
/PATTERN1/ && found1 && !found2{   ##Checking if PATTERN1 in current line and found1 is SET and found2 is NOT SET then do following.
  found1=found2=val=""             ##Nullifying found1, found2 and val variables here.
}
/PATTERN1/{                        ##Checking condition if PATTERN1 is found then do following.
  found1=1                         ##Setting found1 here for flagging.
  next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/PATTERN2/{                        ##Checking condition if PATTERN2 is found then do following.
  found2=1                         ##Setting found2 here for flagging.
  if(found1){                      ##Checking condition if found1 is SET then do following.
    print val                      ##Printing val here.
  }
  found1=found2=val=""             ##Nullifying found1, found2 and val here.
  next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0           ##Creating val which has current line value and keep appending it with new line.
}
' Input_file                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: It took me a minute to snap to you using `PATTERN1[2]` and that's how you did it without an array `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, yeah working for shown samples and I hope this should help OP cheers :)

Comment: Yep, that works like a champ. I just wasn't sure how attached the OP was to the exact patterns listed. No reason not to be.

Comment: thanks! @DavidC.Rankin it's working great! sorry for the late reply :p i kind of found a hack too: 
awk 'f{{x=x"\n"$0}} {from_pattern}/{{x=$0; f=1}} f 
        && /{to_pattern}/ {{print x; f=0}}' {path_to_file}

Answer (score 2):

In `awk` you can do it by saving the `PATTERN..` and comparing each time a `PATTERN..` is encountered. Between the two, you save the elements in an array, and when you have two patterns that don't match -- you output the contents of the array. Otherwise you empty the array and reset your counter, e.g.

```
awk '! /PATTERN/ {
        a[++n]=$0
    }
    /PATTERN/ {
        if ($0 != lastptrn)
            for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
                print a[i]
        delete a
        n=0
        lastptrn=$0
    }
' file
```

**Output**

```
ggg
hhh
iii
```

Answer (score 2):

If `Perl` happens to be your option, would you please try:

```
perl -0777 -ne '/.*PATTERN1\n(.*?)PATTERN2/s && print $1' input
```

Result:

```
ggg
hhh
iii
```

- `-0777` option tells `Perl` to slurp all lines at once.
- `s` option to the regex tells `Perl` to include newline character in metacharacter `.`.
- `.*PATTERN1\n` winds the position until the end of last `PATTERN1`.
- `(.*?)` specifies the shortest match and assign `$1` to the matched lines.

Comment: Perl is the right tool for such problems.. thumps up!..

Answer (score 0):

Another:

```
$ awk '
/PATTERN1/ {                # at starting pattern
    f=1                     # flag up
    b=""                    # reset buffer
    next                    # to exclude the start pattern
}
/PATTERN2/ {                # at ending pattern
    print b                 # output buffer
    exit                    # no need to continue to the end
}
f {                         # when flag up
    b=b (b==""?"":ORS) $0   # buffer records
}' file
```

To include the starting and ending markers, remove the `next` and move `f {...}` before the `/PATTERN2/ {...}`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/PATTERN2/{g;/PATTERN1/{s/[^\n]*\n//p;q}};H;/PATTERN1/h' file
```

Overview: Copy lines from `PATTERN1` up to but not including `PATTERN2` into the hold space and then print the hold space minus the first line.

Processing: Append all lines to the hold space, replacing the hold space by the contents of `PATTERN1` when it matches.

When `PATTERN2` matches, overwrite the pattern space by the hold space and if the pattern space contains `PATTERN1`, remove the first line, print the contents of the pattern space and quit.